# Mixed Hash Algorithm within Certificate Chain

Tags: algorithm, ssl, hash

We have an internal customer which has issued a Root CA using SHA-1 (which both they and us know should be deprecated) and have issued a server certificate from the Root CA with a Hash Algorithm of SHA2. A team member suggested that this cannot be support as all Hash Algorithm of the certificates must match, but having no understanding of the topic I set out to google to find if there are reasons for a mixed hash environment being unsupported as intuitively I thought a leaf certificate should be able to be a lower encryption level than the root. Finding no comprehensive answer I end up here. Our situation raises three questions for me:

Must the Hash Algorithm remain static for each certificate in the chain of trust?

If Hash Algorithm maybe different can bottom certificate be of a higher or lower public key level?

Could each certificate in a chain use a random encryption level?

Comment: Might I suggest that you ask this question on http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

There can be mixed signature algorithms used for the certificates. Apart from that the signature of the root certificate is not checked anyway so the algorithm used their does not matter. The root certificate is trusted just because it is in the local trust store and not because it was signed by somebody (usually signed by itself).